# Cann't give access to certificat and identifiers to my developer

Tags: user-roles, apple-developer, app-store-connect

Since the merge of user roles management between the appstoreconnect and apple developer accounts, i haven't been able to give access to my team on appstoreconnect to the certificats and identifiers.

It's always disabled and I can't check it.

[image: image of checkbox always disabled]

Comment: Are you sure that you have a company developer account and not a personal one?

Comment: Actually that’s one of my client’s account, and now that you’ve said it, this may as well be the case, I’ll get back to it, if you re sure that personnel accounts can’t invite other people to the dev resourses than please add an answer and I’ll make sure to accept it if this turns out correct. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: You can't invite people to resources over at https://developer.apple.com/account with a personal account. Therefore the checkbox is greyed out and not clickable.

Simply go over to https://developer.apple.com/account to check your enrollment. There you can find your "Entity Type" (> Membership)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, i just double checked with another client's account... it s the same. thanks for the heads up